# Что такое проблема YX?

Tags: обсуждение

В сообществе бывают случаи, которые очень похожи на перевернутую проблему XY: пользователь описывает корректно опознанную проблему X, однако ему предлагают решение Y, которое решает проблему либо только формально/в конкретном частном случае, либо и вовсе скрывает видимые признаки проблемы или решает вытекающую проблему X', в то время как автор вопроса искал решение более обширной проблемы:

[image: Ответы на проблему X']

В данном примере автора вопроса волновал не сам приложенный код, а демонстрируемая в нем проблема, однако отвечающие предложили решения именно по преобразованию кода. Автор вопроса интересовался тем, как вообще должна строиться обработка исключений, и какими идеями вдохновлялись создатели описываемой им системы, и ожидал ответ такого характера:

[image: Ответ на проблему X]

Иногда подобная проблема может быть спровоцирована ложным обнаружением проблемы XY:

[image: False positive, commander!]

Такое может происходить по самым разным причинам - от банальной привычки к однотипным вопросам, в которых требуется комментарий именно к примеру кода, до недопонимания между автором вопроса и отвечающим. Если вы столкнулись с тем, что автор вопроса утверждает, что ваше решение не относится к его вопросу, то возможно, кроме всех прочих причин, вы просто недопоняли автора и даете ответ по более частной или более общей проблеме, нежели спрашивал автор вопроса. В этом случае стоит прочитать вопрос еще раз, и, если уверенность в корректности предложенного решения не исчезла, можно попросить автора переформулировать вопрос, чтобы достигнуть взаимопонимания.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)

Comment: @Kromster нет, мой вопрос о другом

Comment: @etki: в таком случае, вынесите пожалуйста TL;DR в шапку вопроса

Comment: Это как бы неудачная попытка чтения мыслей, получается?

Comment: @Kromster, вы пост вообще читали?

Comment: @etki, привели бы что ль ссылки на вопросы, а то почему-то не могу найти их

Comment: @mymedia их никогда не существовало, это просто изображения

Comment: @mymedia, вы пост по ссылке вообще читали?

Comment: Разумеется, в отличие от некоторых ;)

Comment: @VladD или просто невнимательное чтение вопроса